# UIRefreshControl: how to track the critical pull-down distance

Tags: ios, uirefreshcontrol

I would like to modify the appearance of the `UIRefreshControl` after the user has pulled it down enough to trigger the refresh action. For example I would like to have an attributed title "pull down to refresh" that changes into "release to refresh" once the pull down has reached the critical point.

At the moment the only solution I can think about is to override `continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:` from `UIControl` and track vertical displacement from there. In doing so I would have to start some guess and trial to find the right distance (which may also be device-dependent).
Any idea?

Comment: how about tracking changes on the control which owns refresh control (changes in its scroll)

Comment: @JulianKról Do you mean in the UITable view? It could be used for tracking, but not to find out the 'magic value' of vertical displacement. Does it?

Comment: yes in tableview, which inherits from scrollview. You know when the control occurs by checking refreshing flag state so you can get the scroll position at the moment. I don't see anything better for now

Comment: I'll look into this, thanks!

Comment: maybe tableview has some helpful API but I haven't investigated that. This was what comes first to my mind

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @akashsr Nope, sorry... for the time being I'm still living with the problem